# python typing for multiprocessing.Value

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-typing

`multiprocessing.Value("d")` returns a type of `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Synchronized`

So currently I type hint like:
`int_val: Synchronized = multiprocessing.Value("i")`

Is there something like `Synchronized[int]`?  (Similar to lists, and other container types)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/8799